# imagejpeg do not show an a image

Tags: php, imagejpeg

I'm trying generate a certificate to print, but the only thing that happens is show a empty square in screen:

[image]

I'm trying show the image on the screen before i try to write on it.

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$imagem = imagecreatefromjpeg("assets/img/certificado.jpg");
imagejpeg($imagem);
```

I already check the gd2 extension and it's enable:
[image]

And I check the php error log and the page who run this code dont return any error.

When I remove the `header("Content-type:image/jpeg");` and put a `var_dump($i)` it shows me this: `resource(12,gd)`

Sorry for my english and thanks!

Comment: did you `var_dump($imagem)` already? Is it a valid image recource (or false maybe)?

Comment: @Jeff When i remove header("Content-type: image/jpeg") and do this, i receive resource(12, gd)... if i don't remove, nothing happen, only the square

Comment: hm... sounds valid. Are you sure `certificado.jpg` contains an actual image? (could be a blank square too)

Comment: @Jeff certificado.jpg is the certificate background

Comment: Not all jpgs are jpgs maybe try http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php - doesn't care what image it is. may help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$our_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('upload/promo/flyer_hindi.jpg');
$white_color = imagecolorallocate($our_image, 0, 0, 0);
$font_path = 'upload/promo/CALIBRIB.TTF';
$text = 'some text';
$size = 70;
$angle = 0;
$left = 420;
enter code here
imagettftext($our_image, $size, $angle, $left, $top, $white_color, $font_path, $text);
imagejpeg($our_image, 'upload/promo/' . $id . '.jpg', 80);
```

i tried this code a last year, i upload a flyer and add some text on fix location and save. i think you need the same.

Comment: How does that address a (yet unknown) problem the OP has?

Comment: on line 2 i am choosing white color and on line 9 i am deciding where i will write that text.

Comment: @SaurabhSharma Yes, this is what I need in the end ... but now I can not even show the image without writing it. My problem is probably in the imagejpeg() function

Comment: the OP doesn't ask to write text into an image, but just to display an existing one.